# jQuery linked dropdown don´t work when access via browsers

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, wcf

I do have created a Web App in MVC C# with two jQuery dropdown linked this way: the first dropdown shows (from database) all the departments of my country (I do not live in the USA but...hello everyone, your country is beautiful) and once the department is selected the second dropdown must show all the cities(municipios in spanish) of the selected department.

All was working fine when I was debugging from Visual Studio but when I did publish the app and access it via browser(doesn´t matter if the browser is chrome, explorer, firefox) the first dropdown works fine but the second one always sends an error message, the one specified in the `error: function (ex)`

these are the properties of the department and cities

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dptoEvento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Seleccione</span>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dptoEvento, ViewBag.ddlDpto as SelectList, "", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddDepartamentos", @title = "especifique departamento en que impartirá el evento", @Value = ViewBag.dptoEvento })
                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dptoEvento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.municipioEvento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Seleccione</span>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.municipioEvento, ViewBag.ddlMunicipio as SelectList, "", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddMunicipios", @title = "especifique municipio en que impartirá el evento"})
                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.municipioEvento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and this is the jQuery code that populates the dropdown cities once the department is selected

```
$('#ddDepartamentos').change(function () {
    var selectedCountryID = $('#ddDepartamentos').val();

    $('#ddMunicipios').empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/ObtenerMunicipio",
        datatype: "Json",
        data: { id: $('#ddDepartamentos').val() },

        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#ddMunicipios').append('<option value="' + value.Value + '">' + value.Text + '</option>');
                $('#ddMunicipios').attr('disabled', false);
            });
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Error:  ' + ex);
        }
    });
});
```

and the code that retrieves the info for the two dropdowns(It uses a WCF Service and it retrieves the info just fine)

```
 ProxyGFC.ServiceGFCClient cliente = new ProxyGFC.ServiceGFCClient();

ViewBag.ddlDpto = new SelectList(cliente.PoblarDDLDpto(), "codigoDpto", "departamento");
                    ViewBag.ddlMunicipio = new SelectList(cliente.PoblarDDLMunicipio(datos.dptoEvento), "codigoMunicipio", "nombreMunicipio");
```

and for the last, the jQuery libraries

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel=" stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="@Url.Content("/css/modern-business.css")" rel="stylesheet">
```

could you tell me what is wrong? (I got this error on console when prekss F12)

[image]
Edit: just changed the url info  `url: "/Home/ObtenerMunicipio"` for
                `url: '@Url.Action(actionName: "ObtenerMunicipio",` but still doesn´t workcontrollerName: "Home")',

Comment: thanks and yes, I just have updated the question

Comment: That is a 404, meaning there is nothing there.  Put that link directly in your browser and see what happens.  You can pass any variables in the url like /Home/ObtenerMunicipio?id=123456

Comment: I did solve the problem with the url '../Home/ObtenerMunicipio'